# Problem Importing python UDF into Jupyter notebook with PySpark: Can't find module in python source code (/src)

Tags: python, import, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have written a python UDF that uses a previously defined python function rather than a lambda (the standard input to udfs). This seems to be causes a strange import error when the code is executed within a jupyter notebook (e.g., calling df.show() or df.collect())

The structure of the code is simply (in, e.g., src/src_code.py)

```
   class MyClass(pyspark.ml.Transformer):

       def __init__(self, inputCol, outputCol, extra_arg):
           self.inputCol=inputCol
           self.outputCol=outputCol
           self.extra_arg=extra_arg

       def _transform(self, dataset):
         dataset = dataset.withColumn(self.inputCol, F.udf(lambda x: example_python_fn(x, 
             self.extra_arg))(F.col(self.inputCol)))

   def example_python_fn(self, x, extra_arg):
        return x + extra_arg
```

I am trying to use a function call rather than a lambda because I want to pass two variables into the function and this seems like the cleanest way to do it.

I can import this class into a jupyter notebook. But when I run the code for some reason pyspark
try's to import the function (presumably on one of the executors). This results in the error
shown below:

```
line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 580, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

If I copy this code directly into the jupyter notebook (rather than leaving it in src) then the code works perfectly. But I really don't want to do this because it's messy. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You have `def class`. You don’t define a class, you just have `class MyClass`. You’ll encounter that issue when you manage to get the ModuleNoteFound resolved. For that, have you told Spark where it can find other modules? It seems to me the workers simply can't find src, because `src` is not in their PYTHONPATH.

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. Yes I figured that was the case. The question is, why? Why are the workers trying to import from src in this case? And why does it work when the code is added directly into a notebook? And then finally, how can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it. I am facing a similar problem